# Riemann - Prove that $ L(f, [a, b]) + L(g, [a, b]) \le L(f+g, [a, b]) $

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose $f, g: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions. Prove that
> \begin{equation}
>     L(f, [a, b]) + L(g, [a, b]) \le L(f+g, [a, b]) 
> \end{equation}

**My attempt:**

> Suppose $f, g: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are bounded functions. Let $P$ be an arbitrarily fixed partition of $[a, b]$. Note that since $\inf (f+g)\ge\inf f+\inf g$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> L(f+g, P, [a, b]) &= \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j-x_{j-1}) \inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]} (f+g)\\
> &\ge \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j-x_{j-1}) \inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]} f + \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j-x_{j-1}) \inf_{[x_{j-1}, x_j]} g \\
> &= L(f, P, [a, b]) + L(g, P, [a, b])
> \end{align*}
>
> Now, taking suprema on both sides of the inequality above, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \sup_P L(f+g, P, [a, b]) &\ge \sup_P \{L(f, P, [a, b]) + L(g, P, [a, b])\}\\
> &=\sup_P L(f, P, [a, b]) + \sup_PL(g, P, [a, b])
> \end{align*}
>
> where the suprema are taken over all partitions $P$ of $[a, b]$.

Can someone please read over my proof and let me know if there is something that needs to be revised? If revisions are needed, can someone please suggest how these revisions should be made?

Comment: Your last equality is incorrect. $\sup$ of a sum is $\leq$ than the sum of the $\sup$s.

Comment: @Valerin, I think the first sup $\geq$ is correct (if $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x$, then $\sup f \geq \sup g$).  It's the $=$ that's wrong ($\sup(f+g) \leq \sup f + \sup g$). Changing that to $\leq$ is correct but it doesn't get closer to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Mason pointed out, the supremum part is incorrect. You need to show that for any partitions $P, P'$, there exists partition $P^*$ such that:

$$L(f,P,[a,b])+L(g,P',[a,b])≤L(f+g,P^*,[a,b])$$

An easy way to show that is to choose $P^* = P \cup P'$ and show that for any lower integrable function $h: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, $L(h, P^*, [a,b]) \geq L(h, P, [a,b])$ and $L(h, P^*, [a,b]) \geq L(h, P', [a,b]) $.

Once you have that, if you still need help:

> $$L(f+g,P^*,[a,b]) \geq L(f,P^*,[a,b])+L(g,P^*,[a,b]) \geq L(f,P,[a,b])+L(g,P',[a,b])$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on your answer, I was able to show that $L(f+g, [a, b])\ge L(f, P, [a, b])+L(g, P', [a, b])$, but could you please explain how this can be used to conclude that $L(f, [a, b]) + L(g, [a, b]) \le L(f+g, [a, b])$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson Think about the following question for arbitrary real functions $f,g,h$: if $\forall x,y$, $\exists z$ such that $h(z) \geq f(x) + g(y)$, what does that mean about the relationship between $\sup h$ and $\sup f + \sup g$?